# javascript get id from url two options.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have link:

```
      https://localhost:44301/.../.../2e8f0070-ff56-4f88-a316-b6d45f67b749/
```

Then I can get ID from this method:

```
    var index = window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (index > 0 && index + 1 < window.location.href.length) {
                return window.location.href.substring(index + 1);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
```

But if the link is:

```
    https://localhost:44301/.../.../2e8f0070-ff56-4f88-a316-b6d45f67b749#/
```

The hash if from AngularJS routing.

Then how I can obtain the ID without the "#" character?

Comment: `replace #` with empty space.

Comment: `return window.location.href.substring(index + 1).replace('#', '');`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **ui-router**, your code should looks like something like that:

```
.state('stateName', {
  url: '/object/:id',
  controller: 'ObjectCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/object.html'
  ...
});
```

Then, since controller, **you can get access to that id value**, using `$stateParams`

```
(() => {
  app.controller('ObjectCtrl', objectCtrl);
  objectCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams'];
  function objectCtrl($scope, $stateParams) {
    let id = $stateParams.id;
    console.log(id); // prints "2e8f0070-ff56-4f88-a316-b6d45f67b749"
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the hash from the url, using the `replace` function.

```
return window.location.href.substring(index + 1).replace('#', '');
```

This will remove the hash from the string for you.